# How to install the Allegro library on Visual Studio 2008 and Windows Vista for the C programming language?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, graphics

How do you set up to use the full Allegro library on Windows Vista and Visual Studio 2008?

Do you have to compile it or is it only a matter of setting searchpaths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to download a [pre-compiled **MSVC** binary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/alleg/files/allegro-bin/). Then it is just a matter of telling Visual Studio where to find Allegro's *.h headers and *.lib library files. Also the Allegro DLL's need to be somewhere in the system path.

The [Allegro wiki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/alleg/files/allegro-bin/) has instructions for configuring a Visual Studio Express 2008 project...

- with [Allegro 4](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Visual_C%2B%2B_Express_2008) (stable version)
- with [Allegro 5](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro_4.9.x_Binary_for_MSVC_2008_Express) (development version)

Check out the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308952/installing-allegro-c/2529790#2529790) for some other useful Allegro development resources.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a .Net library, download that and add it as a reference in your development project. That should be it.