# Installing allegro c++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to setup `allegro` to work with `visual studio express 2008`. But  I don't know the set of instructions. I want to to recognize the `allegro library`. I would like to get some help regarding the installation procedure.

Comment: Any code this far? Did you make sure the paths in your settings are correct? Do you get any compile errors? linker errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Allegro wiki](http://wiki.allegro.cc/) has instructions for configuring a Visual Studio Express 2008 project...

- with [Allegro 4](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Visual_C%2B%2B_Express_2008) (stable version)
- with [Allegro 5](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro_4.9.x_Binary_for_MSVC_2008_Express) (development version)

Here are some other excellent resources for Allegro-related development:

- Allegro.cc [annotated manual](http://www.allegro.cc/manual/)
- Allegro.cc [forums](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/)
- [Mailing lists](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/maillist.html) for Allegro users and developers